# Changing old email to new email, lost the password

Tags: email, password

Help!  I have been accepted to write a blog for our local newspaper, The Rolla Daily News, in Rolla, MO. I cannot access my wordpress.com blog.  We  moved from a rental house in the country to a new house inside the city limits of Rolla, and that meant having to get a new email address.  I also  cannot remember my password, and as the old email address has been shut down, wordpress can't send me my password via email.  Should I cancel my blog and restart up a new one?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this on wordpress.com? Or do you have a custom installation on your own web server?

Comment: You should contact WordPress.com staff: http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/

Comment: In the future, I highly recommend using [LastPass](http://www.lastpass.com).  It would prevent issues like this!

Answer (score 1):

As per the FAQ, wordpress.com questions, i.e., the  `setup, feature, account, and other user support issues` are outside the scope of WPSE: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

Contact wordpress.com support: http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/